# convert base64 string to image using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, image, wcf, base64

I'm using this function to convert base64 to image.

```
public Image Base64ToImage(string base64String)
{
    // Convert Base64 String to byte[]
    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0,imageBytes.Length))
    {
        // Convert byte[] to Image
        ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
        //Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
        Image image = Image.FromStream(ms,true,true);
        return image;
    }
}
```

but it is not working. please help me.

Comment: i got the error like parameter incorrect

Comment: where do you have a error? Compile error or runtime error, on which line? And post the exception, if you have one.

Comment: it is runtime exception . Image image = Image.FromStream(ms,true,true); here im getting the error

Comment: how about this link ? > http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Converting-Base64-strings-8808c305

Comment: see my answer. I think you are duplicating data in your stream

Comment: I dont know , why my code is not working. im giving you my base64 encoded string, can you pls try and let me know. my string is "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB"

Answer (score 0):

I don't thik the ms write call is needed here.

```
 using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0,imageBytes.Length))
        {
            // Convert byte[] to Image
            ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
```

Your are efectively constructing the stream from your byteArray so the ms.Write call will append the data twice in the stream. This might cause issues for your Image object. Either use the default constructor for the stream or delete the Write and test again.

Edit:
Zey deleted his answer but i think he had a good point in there. You might consider dropping the using block as well. My memory might fail me but i think Image objects need the source stream to be kept open. Dispose the Image object when not needed anymore.

Comment: I dont know , why my code is not working. im giving you my base64 encoded string, can you pls try and let me know. my string is "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB"

Comment: what type of image was that base64 block supposed to represent?. You might have a data corruption issue

Comment: usually base64 strings end in "==" so if what you posted is the entire data you have i think it some parts of it got lost somewhere

Comment: can you say that minimum length of base64 string